# Update PgSQL Self JOIN With Custom Values

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, self-join

I'm trying to use UPDATE SELF JOIN and could not seem to get the correct SQL query.

Before the query, I execute this SQL query to get the values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (purpose) purpose FROM user_assigned_customer
```

- sales_manager
- main_contact
- representative
- administrator

By the time I run this query, it overwrites all the purpose columns:

```
UPDATE user_assigned_customer SET purpose = (
  SELECT 'main_supervisor' AS purpose FROM user_assigned_customer AS assigned_user
  LEFT JOIN app_user ON app_user.id = assigned_user.app_user_id
  WHERE app_user.role = 'supervisor'
  AND user_assigned_customer.purpose IS NULL
  AND assigned_user.id = user_assigned_customer.id
)
```

The purpose column is now only showing when running the first query:

- main_supervisor

Wondering if there is a way to query to update SQL Self JOIN with a custom value.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it with a help of a friend.

```
UPDATE user_assigned_customer SET purpose = 'main_supervisor'
  FROM user_assigned_customer AS assigned_user
  LEFT JOIN app_user ON app_user.id = assigned_user.app_user_id
  WHERE app_user.role = 'supervisor'
  AND user_assigned_customer.purpose IS NULL
  AND assigned_user.id = user_assigned_customer.id
```